# install ImageUtils python

Tags: python, image

I am trying to install ImageUtils, I found the package but it doesn't have an installer with it. what is the procedure?

Comment: on Windows? Did you download the source or the Python egg?

Comment: check this answer first... sounds like you just need the basics of installing a Python package: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471994/what-is-setup-py

Answer (score 0):

The general approach to installing Python packages is to use [`easy_install`](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall), or [`pip`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip); the choice between the two tends to get political, so I will just say I use `pip`. `pip` plays well with [`virtualenv`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), which is a tool that makes it much nicer to explore arbitrary Python packages.

In your case, (assuming you have installed `virtualenv` and `pip`) I would probably do something like the following (assumes Unix-like environment; there should be a Windows equivalent, but I'm not current on what it might be):

1. `virtualenv iu-sandbox`
2. `pip install -E iu-sandbox ImageUtils`
3. `cd iu-sandbox`
4. `source bin/activate`
5. Open the REPL and start exploring `ImageUtils`