# Import "Misc.ImageUtils" could not be resolved

Tags: python-3.x

VSCode, Windows 11, Python 3.12, Pillow 10.2.0, pip,
Extensions: Python, Python Extension Pack, Python Image Preview

I am trying to have ImageUtils. "Import "Misc.ImageUtils" could not be resolved" as a problem.

In code:

```
import Misc.ImageUtils as iu
```

iu text is dark green but Misc.ImageUtils is white with underline squiggle. Misc is dark green on its own if I do `import Misc`, but not ImageUtils.

I have tried `pip install ImageUtils` with no success, as below. I believe I cannot have both Pillow and PIL, so I have Pillow, which should be fine. But below as output I see `imageutils 0.3.8 depends on PIL`.

Trying to install:

```
$ pip install ImageUtils==0.3.8
```

Output:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting ImageUtils==0.3.8
  Using cached imageutils-0.3.8.tar.gz (3.5 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of imageutils to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from imageutils) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PIL
```

Or install without version:

```
$ pip install ImageUtils
```

Output:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting ImageUtils
  Using cached imageutils-0.3.8.tar.gz (3.5 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of imageutils to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
  Using cached ImageUtils-0.3.7.tar.gz (3.5 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
ERROR: Cannot install imageutils==0.3.7 and imageutils==0.3.8 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    imageutils 0.3.8 depends on PIL
    imageutils 0.3.7 depends on PIL

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

This did not help me: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192373/install-imageutils-python](https://stackoverflow.com)