# pylearn2 in windows - trouble with setup.py

Tags: python, windows, module, installation

i am trying to install the Pylearn2 package ([Pylearn2](http://deeplearning.net/software/pylearn2/)) in windows. I am using the Spyder/Anaconda IDE to work with python.

Inside the source files there is a script called setup.py. However, when i try to run it i get the following error message:

```
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
or: setup.py --help-commands
or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied`
```

And the interpreter stops working. Here is the code inside the setup.py script:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='pylearn2',
    version='0.1dev',
    packages=find_packages(),
    description='A machine learning library build on top of Theano.',
    license='BSD 3-clause license',
    long_description=open('README.rst').read(),
    install_requires=['numpy>=1.5', 'theano', 'pyyaml', 'argparse'],
    package_data={
    '': ['*.txt', '*.rst', '*.cu', '*.cuh', '*.h'],
    },
)
```

I really don`t know what to do. I searched the web, but didn't find much help.
Please, help if you can.

Comment: python setup.py build && python setup.py install - common usage possible duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1472014/2620328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually for setup.py:

```
>python setup.py build && python setup.py install
```

Full documentation: [here](http://docs.python.org/2/install/) with more detailed info!