# Install python packages to correct anaconda environment

Tags: python, setup.py, anaconda

I've setup anaconda and created a python 3.3 environment. Now I wanted to install some package ([dataset](https://dataset.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)). The install instructions ask to clone the git repo and run

```
python setup.py install
```

but now the packages are not installed to the environments site-packages folder but to a different anaconda location.

What are the normal steps to solve that problem? Newbie-compatible solutions are preferred. The OS is MacOSX, just is case, it is relevant.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It looks like conda automatically adds pip to your conda environment, so after you source your conda environment, i.e.:

```
source activate ~/anaconda/envs/dataset
```

you should be able to install it like this:

```
git clone git://github.com/pudo/dataset.git
pip install ./dataset
```

**EDIT**

Here are the exact steps I took:

```
$ conda create -p ~/anaconda/envs/py33 python=3.3 anaconda pip
$ source activate ~/anaconda/envs/py33
$ which pip
~/anaconda/envs/py33/bin/pip
$ pip install ./dataset/
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work - the env is called py3k and there is no bin/activate in that environment. I've activated it though. And `pip install ./dataset` installs to `~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages` like `python setup.py install` but I need the packages in `~/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages`

Comment: @Andreas_D, was pip included in your conda installation?

Comment: My guess is that pip wasn't included in your py3k environment. Try `conda install pip` in that environment first. It works for me, although I'm not on a Mac.

Comment: Now I've executed `conda install -n py3k pip` and it looked like it installed some py33 related packages. But `pip install ./dataset` still uses the python2.7 path (and reports requirements already satisfied)

Comment: What version are you using? I've got `conda 3.0.6`.

Comment: Strike!! I've activated the environment again(!) and now it runs like a charm. Thanks a lot for your patience! (Reason for fail: the `~/.profile` exported a wrong path, didn't point to the environment)

Comment: Usually just doing `source activate py33` will work. ?

Comment: I thought you're not supposed to use pip with conda?

Comment: It does not work very well if you have a package that requires native compilation.

Comment: I have tried many tricks, but none worked! The effortless way to solve this, for now, is just to copy the installed folder from the wrong environment to the equivalent folder in your targeted environment.