# Is it feasible to write setup.py that will work with both python.org Python and Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda

The closest I found is this: [Install python packages to correct anaconda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22312665/5691066)

Unfortunately, the answer given in this question doesn't help.  I cannot use `pip`, because, for my purposes, `pip` is broken (far too many bugs).  My `setup.py`, uses `sys.prefix` to do various things, like copying some static data files, coordinating some packages about those data etc.

I cannot use wheel format for deploying my code because it is also fundamentally broken (no way to specify absolute paths).

I've been looking at Anaconda as a possible alternative solution for deploying my project, but I'm new to the whole system, and may be missing something obvious.

I was trying to install things in an environment created by `conda`, but very quickly discovered that `sys.prefix` in this environment is set to the directory where Anaconda itself is installed (and it is not writable).  Since then, I was looking for packaging guide for Anaconda, but all I found so far is very superficial: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs.html - I need to do a lot more than just declare dependencies in deployment script.  Things like locating appropriate C compiler, Go compiler, utilities like `bison` and `flex` and so on.

---

Finally, my question is: is it at all feasible to use `setup.py install` with Anaconda?  Should I try to go down that route, or should I do it differently?  Maybe there's a way to build binary packages for Anaconda that I didn't discover yet?

Answer (score 0):

This may answer partially your question. I have a package that is installed with `setup.py` in anaconda on windows and also in a ubuntu server. To handle that problem with the `sys.prefix`, when creating your environment, specify explicitly which python version you want:

```
  conda create --name my_env python=3.5
```

then check your `sys.prefix` and it should be the environment folder.