# Graph Theory in Networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am starting to use this interface now, I have some experience with Python but nothing extensive. I am calculating the transitivity and community structure of a small graph:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.read_edgelist(data, delimiter='-', nodetype=str)
nx.transitivity(G)

#find modularity
part = best_partition(G)
modularity(part, G)
```

I get the transitivity just fine, however - there is the following error with calculating modularity.

```
NameError: name 'best_partition' is not defined
```

I just followed the documentation provided by the networkx site, is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I can tell `best_partition` isn't part of networkx. It looks like you want to use https://sites.google.com/site/findcommunities/ which you can install from https://bitbucket.org/taynaud/python-louvain/src

Once you've installed `community` try this code:

```
import networkx as nx
import community
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.random_graphs.powerlaw_cluster_graph(300, 1, .4)
nx.transitivity(G)

#find modularity
part = community.best_partition(G)
mod = community.modularity(part,G)

#plot, color nodes using community structure
values = [part.get(node) for node in G.nodes()]
nx.draw_spring(G, cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet'), node_color = values, node_size=30, with_labels=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**edit:** How I installed the community detection library

```
ryan@palms ~/D/taynaud-python-louvain-147f09737714> pwd
/home/ryan/Downloads/taynaud-python-louvain-147f09737714
ryan@palms ~/D/taynaud-python-louvain-147f09737714> sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Comment: I am not familiar with bitbucket.org. Is there a file to download? Furthermore, it says "python setup.py install", where exactly do I type this? I get a syntax error when I write it in a script. Thanks so much.

Comment: I also tried running "python setup.py install" in command line, and got the same error.

Comment: follow the link on the left for "Downloads", extract the file, cd into the directory, and enter the setup.py command from there

Comment: I am sorry this must seem extremely stupid. But where exactly do I type in setup.py install?

Comment: see edit (though you probably just want "python" and not "python3")

Comment: I'm not familiar with this notation:
Are you installing the package in your Downloads folder?

Comment: look at https://docs.python.org/2/install/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471994/what-is-setup-py

Answer (score 2):

I just met the same error `NameError: name 'best_partition' is not defined` when using [this](http://perso.crans.org/aynaud/communities/) example code.

This error occurs because I named my python file as `networkx.py`, then when we execute this program

```
import networkx as nx
```

This program may import the `networkx` we defined instead of the library. In the program, `best_partition` is not defined. So this error occur.

Having same name with library is not appropriate. Maybe you should check this!