# Deploy scrapyd spider with external packages

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

The scrapyd docs include the following note:

> scrapyd-deploy won’t deploy anything outside the project module...

Does that mean that I cannot import from site-packages in my spiders?

My spiders rely on external libraries such as MySQL-python and tldextract.  Must I include these libraries within the project module and import from the include libraries as opposed to site-packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Deploying your project](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html#deploying-a-project) documentation paragraph should clarify things:

> Finally, to deploy your project use:
>
> ```
> scrapyd-deploy scrapyd -p project1
> ```
>
> This will eggify your project and
>   upload it to the target, printing the JSON response returned from the
>   Scrapyd server. If you have a `setup.py` file in your project, that one
>   will be used. Otherwise a `setup.py` file will be created automatically
>   (based on a simple template) that you can edit later.

In other words, you would/should have `MySQL-python`, `tldextract` or other dependencies listed in [`setup.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471994/what-is-setup-py) which would be automatically installed during deployment.

Comment: This isn't working, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46401469/2641128

Answer (score 0):

I found some evidence (i.e. gitHub posts [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/issues/246) and [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/pull/269)) that suggests installation of custom packages via the 'setup.py' file is not (and will not) be supported. Since I'm running scrapyd in a docker container, my workaround is:

1. Ensure the necessary external Python packages are installed in the scrapyd container by calling `pip install <package>` in the Dockerfile.
2. Create a bind mount in the container which links to any custom modules external to the scrapy project directory. I entered the below lines for my scrapyd service in my docker-compose file (note that the mount point must be created in the container's '/tmp' directory):

> ```
> volumes:         
>   - custom_module:/tmp/custom_module
> ```