# Scrapy-deploy to Scrapyd doesn't install requirements pointed in setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, scrapy, scrapyd

I have a project written with Scrapy. This spider has a lot of requirements in setup.py. Here is a simple **example**. I run

```
scrapyd-deploy
```

and have the following output

```
Packing version 1506254163
Deploying to project "quotesbot" in http://localhost:6800/addversion.json
Server response (200):
......................... [CUTTED TRACEBACK] ...........
\"/private/var/folders/xp/c949vlsd14q8xm__dv0dx8jh0000gn/T/quotesbot-1506254163-e50lmcfx.egg/quotesbot/spiders/toscrape-css.py\",
 line 4, in <module>\n
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'\n"}
```

BUT

```
setup.py in the same directory:

# Automatically created by: scrapyd-deploy

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name         = 'quotesbot',
    version      = '1.0',
    packages     = find_packages(),
    entry_points = {'scrapy': ['settings = quotesbot.settings']},
    install_requires=[
        'scrapy-splash',
         [ SOME REQUIREMENTS]
        'sqlalchemy'
    ],
)
```

Comment: This is a fresh deploy or a redeploy of the spider?

Comment: this is a initial deploy of the spider. First time ever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked `scrapyd` source code and it doesn't run `setup.py` of your project. It just unpacks the egg which contains the dependency information but not the dependency itself. Below is the code for addversion api

```
class AddVersion(WsResource):

    def render_POST(self, txrequest):
        project = txrequest.args[b'project'][0].decode('utf-8')
        version = txrequest.args[b'version'][0].decode('utf-8')
        eggf = BytesIO(txrequest.args[b'egg'][0])
        self.root.eggstorage.put(eggf, project, version)
        spiders = get_spider_list(project, version=version)
        self.root.update_projects()
        UtilsCache.invalid_cache(project)
        return {"node_name": self.root.nodename, "status": "ok", "project": project, "version": version, \
            "spiders": len(spiders)}
```

After `self.root.eggstorage.put(eggf, project, version)` which basically just extract the egg, it directly runs `spiders = get_spider_list(project, version=version)` and hence there is no setup done as such.

So either your egg needs to include all the dependencies, which means you won't build the egg using `scrapyd-deploy`. I couldn't find much documentation to see if that is possible or not

So what you are seeing is because of srapyd lacking the implementation. You should open a bug or enhancement request at http://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/

Comment: There is one issue for this matter https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/issues/246

Answer (score 1):

In [the scrapyd documentation](https://pypi.org/project/scrapyd-client/) under the "*Including dependencies*" section, it says :

> If your project has additional dependencies, you can either install them on the Scrapyd server, or you can include them in the project’s egg, in two steps:
>
> Create a requirements.txt file at the root of the project
>
> Use the --include-dependencies option when building or deploying your project:
> `scrapyd-deploy --include-dependencies`

When it says the requirements.txt needs to be in the root of the project, it is referring to the scraper project root directory.