# Unable to install package using setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py

I tried to install a python package using setup.py but failed.

Any idea about that? I am on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
pip install setup.py
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is setup.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471994/what-is-setup-py)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just mixed up something.Have a look at [pip install usage](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#usage) and [Installing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html).

If you want to download a module source distribution and install it, you should unpack the archive  into a similarly-named directory: `foo-1.0`. Additionally, the distribution will contain a setup script `setup.py`,and then run this command from a terminal:

```
python setup.py install
```

You can use `pip install` if you want to install packages from:

- PyPI (and other indexes) using requirement specifiers.
- VCS project urls.
- Local project directories.
- Local or remote source archives.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @vish make sure `setup.py` is in your  the current directory,`cd  yourpackage`

Comment: I've installed using above steps.

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to the folder containing the package

```
eg: cd /Desktop/packages/foo-1.0/
```

you can install the package either by

```
python setup.py install
```

or by

```
pip install ./
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `python setup.py install`