# How to install nltk_data as package with pip?

Tags: python, pip, nltk

I am new at Python and coming from Java background.

I've got a project, which uses `nltk` and `nltk_data`. I downloaded `nltk_data` with `nltk.download()` on my laptop and the project works fine but I would like to automate the downloading of `nltk_data`.

I can download it from command line but I want to do it lazily as `pip` downloads package upon `pip install`. So my questions are:

- Can I install `nltk_data` as a regular Python package with `pip` ?
- What is the best way to download `nltk_data` lazily ?

Comment: It's not possible with pip because `nltk_data` is not a python library but just a repository of files. Use `python -m nltk.downloader all`.

Comment: Thanks. Turned out I need just a subset of all those `nltk_data`. What is the best way to "pack" this subset as my project dependency to distribute my program ?

Comment: Which dataset do you need?

Comment: `corpora/stopwords`, `stemmers`, and `tokenizers`.

Comment: I don't want to store these data in git because it's an external dependency rather than my project code. On the other hand I don't want to download `nltk_data` each time one builds the project. That's why I am wondering how to pack `nltk_data` as a python package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bottom of the [NLTK data documentation](http://www.nltk.org/data.html#command-line-installation) explains this:

> Run the command `python -m nltk.downloader all`. To ensure central installation, run the command `sudo python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/local/share/nltk_data all`.

If you want to distribute your program, you might want to consider writing a `setuptools` `setup.py` file to simplify installation:

[What is setup.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471994/what-is-setup-py)

[Official packaging docs](https://packaging.python.org/distributing/#configuring-your-project)