# How to pack and distribute python program (.py source code) so that other developers can easily install all required dependencies?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deployment, pip, python-module

I'm developing a Python application built with some packages I've installed with pip such as Flask, requests, PIL.

So how can I distribute my program so that other people can easily install every required dependency/package and simply make it work on every computer? Is setup.py what I'm looking for or not at all? If so, could you please explain what it does and provide an example setup.py that does what I'm trying to do?

PS: I've also got this little question: do I need to provide a __init__.py in the top level folder of my program or just in subdirectories?

Comment: provide a setup file, in which you perform a check for each dependency

Comment: Elia, sorry I didn't understand well your question at first. Yes, you are looking for a setup.py, is the best way to do it

Comment: You can follow the guide [here](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: @DamianLattenero I'm looking to share/distribute my application in the form of .py files and I'd like to include a simple and easy way of installing missing packages. Also my project is an application per-se / standalone, it's not meant to be imported in other projects, is other words: it's not supposed to be a library, just a program, I don't know if this makes any difference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the not so old days I used [this guide](https://packaging.python.org/distributing/) to learn how to package and distribute my python code, then some good people created [flit](http://flit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which allows me to do the whole process in three steps.

```
$pip install flit
```

Create my metadata file:

```
[metadata]
author=Some guy
author-email=some-email@nowhere.com
home-page=https://github.com/someuser/somepackage
requires=requests
requires-python= >=3
description-file=README.rst
classifiers=Intended Audience :: Developers
    License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3
    Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules
```

Publish my package:

```
$pip flit publish
```

And done!!!

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation [here](https://www.fullstackpython.com/application-dependencies.html)

> setup.py
>
> There is another type of dependency specification for Python libraries
>   known as setup.py. Setup.py is a standard for distributing and
>   installing Python libraries. If you're building a Python library, such
>   as requests or underwear you must include setup.py so a dependency
>   manager can correctly install both the library as well as additional
>   dependencies for the library. There's still quite a bit of confusion
>   in the Python community over the difference between requirements.txt
>   and setup.py, so read this well written post for further
>   clarification.

Also check this:

[What is setup.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471994/what-is-setup-py)

You can see this example to have an idea of how to make yours:

https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/master/setup.py

Also, there is a guide here:

https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html

Answer (score 2):

[here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/setup.py) is the link to the setup file of pandas, where you can see how they perform checks for their dependencies, they might be platform specific or any third party package specific

Comment: that's a good answer! Nice to provide an example so he can follow a path, +1

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, python packaging has [a complicated history](http://7ych.blogspot.com/2017/10/an-illustrated-history-of-python.html), and new tools are still emerging. My understanding is that the current "gold standard" is to use `setup_tools` to define a `setup.py` file. This file will allow others to install your project's source code using pip. If you want to be able to install with pip without explicitly downloading the source first, you will need to [publish your project to pypi](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#uploading-your-project-to-pypi) using `python setup.py upload`.

Below is the `setup.py` boilerplate I use as a starting point:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
""" boilerplate for new project setup.py """

from setuptools import setup
import io

import projectname

def read(*filenames, **kwargs):
    encoding = kwargs.get('encoding', 'utf-8')
    sep = kwargs.get('sep', '\n')
    buf = []
    for filename in filenames:
        with io.open(filename, encoding=encoding) as f:
            buf.append(f.read())
    return sep.join(buf)

long_description = read('README.md') #, 'CHANGES.txt')

setup(name='projectname',
    version=projectname.__version__,
    description='short desc of projectname',
    long_description=long_description,
    author='Tylar Murray',
    author_email='code+projectname@tylar.info',
    url='https://github.com/7yl4r/projectname',

    tests_require=['nose'],
    install_requires=[
        'networkx'  # or whatever
    ],
    #cmdclass={'test': PyTest},

    packages=['projectname', 'OtherProjectProvidedPackage2']
)
```

NOTE: this template requires you to have a `README.md` and something like `__version__="0.1.23"` in your top-level `__init__.py`

Regarding your P.S. question: Technically you should open a new question for this but in short the answer is you should include both as covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911789/why-do-i-need-init-py-at-every-level) and in [this answer particularly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21019300/1483986).