# Installing python packages without using pip

Tags: python, installation

I am trying to install a python package (tia) but I am behind a proxy at work, so i cant install anything using pip/conda.

Usually I have found the tz.gar installation files for a package and installed it manually. But with this tia package I havent been able to locate that file.

Do any of you have any other ideas how I can install  packages without pip/conda and without the tz.gar file? (I dont have any passowords for the proxy and I dont want to try to bypass it somehow)

Comment: have you tried: pip install --proxy http://user:password@proxyserver:port package or pip install --proxy http://proxyserver:port package ?

Comment: Yes, I get a long list of red errors in the prompt

Comment: You can try to pip install from github. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch

Or you can download the github repo and run `python setup.py install`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471994/what-is-setup-py

Comment: Well, [there is a `.zip` file in PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tia), have tried that one?

Comment: Which operating system you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you do have access to the GitHub source code of tia.

https://github.com/bpsmith/tia

You can clone this repo, copy it over and then simply run

```
cd your-cloned-repo
pip install -e .
```

or you can also use

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: I would recommend still doing a `pip install` on the cloned directory

Comment: Ahh cloning the repo and using the python setup.py install command worked. Thanks!