# Trouble importing module in Python 2.7

Tags: python, importerror, python-idle

My Mac computer has Python 3.6 and Python 2.7 and I have successfully installed the basic modules such as numpy, scipy and matplotlib, for example, by doing the routine pip install and pip3 install. My Python 3.6 works totally well in Anaconda-Jupiter-Notebook, IDLE and Terminal, while Python 2.7 works only in terminal but not in IDLE.

[image: Terminal - OK]

[image]

Then for version check I tried

```
pip --version
```

Returning: 
pip 10.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)

```
pip3 --version
```

Returning:
pip 10.0.1 from /Users/son520804/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

Then,

```
which python2
```

Returning:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2

```
which pip2
```

Returning:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip2

How could I resolve this issue and enable the Python 2.7 idle to import the modules? Much appreciated for your help.

Comment: Try installing packages with setup.py. Here is how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471994/what-is-setup-py

Answer (score 2):

```
find / -iname '*numpy*'
```

This is a terminal operation not a python command, you can try running that in the terminal to see where it's storing numpy, but you'll probably get the python3's version.

Try:

```
pip2 uninstall numpy
```

Then:

```
pip2 install numpy
```

It might be due to your machine seeing python3 as your default "python" so pip might actually be installing it again to python3. By denoting pip2 it should be linked to python2 (might actually need to do 'pip2.7'). Hope it helps!

Comment: other than restarting the computer, using sudo pip install numpy, or restarting the IDLE, i'm not sure. Make sure to uninstall the modules as well and to reinstall them incase something went wrong.

Comment: It turns out a weird problem...... Now I worked out partially that if I open the Python 2.7 IDLE first, and then open the file and run, it is now OK.. But if I click on open for that file, the same import error occurs. (WTF?)

Comment: It probably has something to do with conflicting paths from anaconda/python2/python3. You should probably use virtual environments or use pyenv from here: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your `pip` is an alias to `pip3`. Find it out by `pip --version` and if so install packages for `python 2.7` as `pip2.7 install matplotlib`

Comment: I also tried this and returned requirement already satisfied, but I still failed to import the module in IDLE. Something went wrong that I don't know.