# lmdb package cannot be imported

Tags: python, pip, python-2.x, lmdb, site-packages

I wanted to use lmdb package in python2.7 on my OSX.

I used `pip2 install lmdb` to install it. And if I install it multiple times, it will show `Requirement already satisfied: lmdb in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (0.94)`.

But then when I open python2.7 in terminal and try to `import lmdb`, an error came out: `ImportError: No module named lmdb`.

Why can't I import the package when it's already in the site-packages directory?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my post and I think we have the same issue, [Trouble importing module in Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691683/trouble-importing-module-in-python-2-7/50691768?noredirect=1#comment88393562_50691768)

Try this out:

If you are using Mac, then open application -> Python 2.7 -> run the two command documents, and then open the IDLE. Then you open the file and run, it might work, although it is counterintuitive.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I only found one command document in Python 2.7 directory, which is `Update Shell Profile.command`. Were you referring to that?

Comment: I'm still not able to `import lmdb` in terminal or python file after opening IDLE first.

Comment: Hi, I tried `pip2 install lmdb` again and it installed the package to another directory: `Requirement already satisfied: lmdb in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and then everything goes well. I guess this has something to do with the command document you mentioned. Thank you.

Comment: Thats a weird thing that if you have already installed Python 3.6 first. And I don't know either why we have to do such weird step to make everything well