# Turning Python script into CLI and enabling its distribution

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-interface

I have a Python file called recognize.py, which takes multiple images and performs OCR with multiple processes, where `ocr_tools` is a large self-written module:

```
import argparse
import json
from multiprocessing import Pool
from ocr_tools import Organize
organizer = Organize()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Recognize the contents on a lab report and return a json string.")
parser.add_argument("-i", "--image", nargs="*", required=True, help="path to input image file")
args = parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool() as p:
        report_set = json.dumps({"report_set": p.map(organizer.finalize_report, args.image)}, ensure_ascii=False)
        print(report_set)
```

For `ocr_tools`, I also have a requirements.txt generated by [pipreqs](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs) for users to install the required packages from [PyPI](https://pypi.org):

```
numpy==1.14.3
regex==2018.2.21
requests==2.18.4
pandas==0.23.0
opencv_python==3.4.1.15
scikit_learn==0.19.1
```

If I distribute these files and modules, users should be able to execute `python recognize.py --image <path_to_an_image>` from the command lines and get OCR results after they install those packages listed in requirements.txt.

*Now I wonder if there's a way to further enable users to do something like `ocr --image <path_to_an_image>`, i.e. the same job without specifying `python` interpreter in the command lines.*

I've read a tutorial, [How Do I Make My Own Command-Line Commands Using Python?](https://dbader.org/blog/how-to-make-command-line-commands-with-python) but it seems effective only locally and cannot be distributed. I've also glanced [Writing the Setup Script](https://docs.python.org/3.6/distutils/setupscript.html), hoping to find solutions for distribution. However, I don't find a way to specify external packages to be installed from PyPI. (Or maybe I missed something - I am a beginner in Python.) Besides, setup.py seems like neither a good way to install the packages according to [comments under the accepted answer of What is setup.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471994/what-is-setup-py/1472014#1472014), nor being capable of enabling CLI.

Comment: There are numerous ways to package Python scripts, which platform(s) is this targeting?

Comment: @l'L'l It should be on Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: If your Python package/script gets installed in a standard place you could simply create an alias for it (eg. `alias ocr=/path/to/recognize.py`)...

Comment: @l'L'l Yes I am aware of that approach and that's somehow like my attached tutorial. However that's still effective only on _my_ workstation. For others who get the scrips (from GitHub for example), they need to set this by themselves. I am seeking a way to do all the needed settings for _them_.