# Pip install and run git repo

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, pip, pypi

I'm trying to pip install a separate git repo into my python project. Pip install seems to work when I run `pip install git+https://github.com/XxdpavelxX/myapp`. However when I then run my code I get the following error.

Here's my app: https://github.com/XxdpavelxX/myapp

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp'
ERROR: could not load /Users/myUser/stuff/callerFile.py
```

Here's the `callerFile.py` (in a separate git repo):

```
from myapp import test
print test.random_print()
```

I suspect that this is `pip install` related. When I run `pip install git+https://github.com/XxdpavelxX/myapp` it seems to pass, however inside of my python `venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages` I only see `myapp-1.0py3.7.eggs-info` instead of the actual package. Anyone knowing what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to add my library to pypi for this to work?

Edit: Added the actual url to github repo I'm testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a folder called myapp and move the __init__.py and test.py files to that folder.

[image]

Add the following line to your setup.py (I added after url),

```
packages=['myapp'],
```

Now installation will be successful and you can import your package.

[What is setup.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471994/what-is-setup-py)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to post your code to pypi.
I suggest you to use tag  `#egg` to set package name.
So the pip status would be like

`pip install git+https://github.com/myGitUser/myLibrary#egg=myLibrary`

Comment: furthermore you can add `--process-dependency-links` on the back to process boto3 and selenium as well.

Comment: Still getting the same error. I modified the question and included the actual github repo so it's easier to debug

Answer (score 1):

Your package has neither [`py_modules`](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#py-modules) nor [`packages`](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#packages) hence it doesn't install anything importable when installed.

My advice is to rename your `__init__.py` to `myapp.py` and add this to `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    …
    py_modules=['myapp'],
    …
)
```