# Installing python package with setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, python-packaging

While installing `mypy_extensions 0.4.3` i ran into

> ValueError: ZIP does not support timestamps before 1980

First part of traceback before `ValueError` raised:

```
creating 'dist\mypy_extensions-0.4.3-py3.7.egg' and adding 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' to it
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 43, in <module>
    'typing >= 3.5.3; python_version < "3.5"',
```

Source Distribution was downloaded from: https://pypi.org/project/mypy-extensions/#files

As was recommended in [What is setup.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471994/what-is-setup-py) answers I try to install package with:

```
python setup.py install
```

But firstly extract the archive into some folder and select directory `cd C:\Users\someuser\folder_with_unarchived_package`

python ver is `3.7.0`

What i do wrong?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where did you lunch the command ? @Doppie

Comment: If I get you question right, 
in the directory with sdist ```C:\Users\someuser\folder_with_unarchived_package```.

Comment: Why don't you directly install this using pip, e.g. ``python3 -m pip install mypy-extensions``? Are you aware of ``typing-extensions``?