# Python3 Cannot Load Module Within sys.path

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

Colleagues!

Consider this code:

```
import os, sys, glob
_p = glob.glob(os.path.abspath(os.environ['MY_ROOTDIR'] +
        '/opensrc/Python-*/lib/python*/site-packages/my_pkg'))
if _p and os.path.isfile(_p[0] + '/__init__.py'):
  sys.path.insert(0, _p[0])
  from my_pkg.all import *
else:
  print("FATAL: Cannot find valid my_pkg module.")
  quit()
```

Adding print statements shows that `sys.path` is what I expect and that my_pkg's `__init__.py` is found in that directory.

Nevertheless, the code leads to an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_pkg'
```

As you can see, we have a `my_pkg` installed in the `site-packages` of a particular Python directory.  I want to load that package, no matter the Python version that is being used.  There's no code in the `__init__.py` that checks Python versions or anything of the sort.

Why can Python not load the module?  Is there a technical reason that I cannot load a module from below the `site-packages` of a different Python release?  If there was some kind of code issue, I'd expect to see that choke instead of just `can't find it...`.

How can I best debug this?

Thanks!

SOLVED:  The solution (provided by @VPfB) is add ONLY the path down to `site-packages`.  Including the name of the module in the path is unnecessary.  I will be careful about any OTHER modules that might come from that directory since I'm inserting at the first position in `sys.path`.

Comment: Maybe you need to install `my_pkg` using pip (e.g: run `pip install -e .` from inside the `my_pkg` directory). Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471994/what-is-setup-py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in wrong subdirectory:

If you have `/some/path/my_pkg/__init__py`, then the `my_pkg` package can be found in the `/some/path` directory. Your code inserts into the `sys.path` the `/some/path/my_pkg` directory instead.

Comment: That's it!  Thanks @VPfB!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.