# How can I make setup.py to include a class into packaging

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I'm using setup.py to package my project. the structure is like:

```
foo -
    |
    |--foo/
    |    |
    |    |--first.py
    |    |--second.py
    |    |--...
    |--README
    |--requirements.txt
    |--scripts/
    |        |
    |        |-script1.sh
    |        |-script2.py
    |--service.py
    |--setup.py
```

If I run the current setup.py, which is in accordance with the suggestions here: [What is setup.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471994/what-is-setup-py)
then in the `venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foo` and `venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scripts` I can see all python classes there. But service.py is absent. My question is how to modify the setup.py to include service.py into packaging such that I can find service.py at `venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For top level modules, such as `service.py`, to be included in the distributions, *setuptools* offers the `py_modules` parameter.

The *setuptools* documentation does not show it clearly, but it is the same as in (now deprecated) *distutils*:

- https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-individual-modules

```
setuptools.setup(
    # ...
    py_modules=['service'],  # no '.py'
)
```

Comment: @YiboLiu Does that answer the question? Anything else?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get notified. Yes that solved the problem. Thank you very much!