# Python: Resolving imports when the modules are in a parent directory above the application root

Tags: python, module, importerror, absolute-path

I am create a little package of packages to facilitate some work. The problem I am encountering is this error message `ImportError: Attempted Relative Import With No Known Parent Package`. I have been googling around as to how to resolve this, but I have not found anything that works.

So here is the package structure. Notice that the applications are in these subfolders, and hey draw upon some modules that are at a higher level.

```
- Project_folder
  - Callbacks
    - PrintingCallback.py
    - LoggingCallback.py

  - DataModules
    - preprocess.py
    - utils.py

  - app1
    - app1.py

  - app2
    - app2.py

  - app3
    - app3.py
```

So the main action is in the `app1.py` or `app2.py` command line app. I am using the `hydra` framework for the CLI. BUT, those python apps need to import the `Callbacks` and `DataModules` folder and the files in there. So how would I go about importing the `preprocess.py` module into `app1.py`? That is the real question.

I tried using an absolute path, like `from Callback.LoggingCallback import LoggingCallback`, then then that still generated the error message `ImportError: Attempted Relative Import With No Known Parent Package`. So is there a better way to do this that is reasonably pythonic?

Comment: Please post the exact Traceback, especially since the usage of the absolute import should not produce that message, my suspicion is whatever import statement inside `LoggingCallback` may be the culprit.  In any case, you should turn your project into an [actual package via a `setup.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39811884/) if you want imports to work correct in a more general case.

Comment: You should create a proper Python project structure. This usually means to have the main module (the one started) in the project root. This will add the project root folder to the `PYTHONPATH` and make it the base for imports. Also you will have to add `__init__.py` files to your sub folder. This will make them a package and therefore importable.

Comment: Thanks @metatoaster and Klaus. Yeah the idea of creating a separate package does make sense. Sides like the best idea. That is pretty easy to do, so I will give that a shot. Thanks for the suggestion.