# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hello_world'

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to run a python test in Azure DevOps and the only error I'm receiving is this:

```
==================================== ERRORS ====================================
_________________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/test_handler.py __________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/vsts/work/1/s/tests/unit/test_handler.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.12/x64/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/unit/test_handler.py:5: in <module>
    from hello_world import app
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hello_world'
----------- generated xml file: /home/vsts/work/1/s/test-output.xml ------------
```

I'm really not sure why it's saying "No module named 'hello_world'"? Here is my YAML configuration for my pipeline, is this the issue?

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
strategy:
  matrix:
    Python37:
      python.version: '3.7'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
  displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'

- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -r hello_world/requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'

- script: |
    pip install pytest pytest-azurepipelines
    pytest
  displayName: 'pytest'
```

Comment: You don't seem to be installing your "hello_world" module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to load `hello_world` as a module, you need to first make it installable and install it. You can do this by simply creating a `setup.py` file (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39811884/12519564) for example), after which you can install your `hellow_world` package by `pip install -e .`, where `-e` means "editable" so that you do not need to reinstall every time you make any change to the source code in `hellow_world`.