# Yet another python path question (relative/absolute/any, really)

Tags: python

I tried to solve this using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028000/how-to-read-a-static-file-from-inside-a-python-package), but I just can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my structure, essentially I'm just writing some basic scripts to help me manage some board game stats I keep.

```
<workspace>
  +-- win_loss/
    +-- KeyForgeWL.py
    +-- DB/
      +-- KeyForgeData.txt
```

Easy enough.  I'm trying to run KeyForgeWL.py, and I want to import data from its sub directory.  With the previous answer, I tried this:

```
import importlib.resources as pkg_resources
from . import DB
```

I then get: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Fine.  I convert it to:

```
import importlib.resources as pkg_resources
from win_loss import DB
```

That gets me: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win_loss'.

So... I'm at a loss.  What am I missing?

Comment: You need a file called `__init__.py` to make a directory a module. An empty one will do, but it has to be there.

Comment: I have added a `__init__.py` in both the win_loss directory, and the DB directory, and it doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: I have to admit, this is one of the most infuriating question in Python: how to get started with a project? I now systematically go the next step and create a `setup.py` and install my project using `pip install -e .` on the project. Why there isn't a simpler solution, I don't know...

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471994/what-is-setup-py

Comment: While it may seem hard to figure out how to create your setup.py now, it's worth it, it'll save you a lot of headaches in the future.

Comment: That honestly feels like overkill for a bunch of random scripts, isn't?  That's going to be annoying as heck if I have to do that just for something like this.

Comment: Agreed, it is. There might be a simpler solution, but I don't know it. Hopefully someone else here does.

Comment: But I believe part of the reason there are so many questions about this on SO is precisely that there is no really simple solution.

Comment: Fair. Well, no harm in learning setup if that will actually solve this, too

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deal with `setup.py` the easiest thing to do is to set `$PYTHONPATH` to the current directory. Using your above example if the current working directory is `<workspace>`  you should run

`export PYTHONPATH=.`

followed by

`python win_loss/KeyForgeWL.py`.

Edit: to clarify the import within the python script should look like this

```
import importlib.resources as pkg_resources
from win_loss import DB
```

as opposed to using the relative import.

Comment: Be aware: `PYTHONPATH` is an egregious hack only for testing, don't use it for real code. Write an actual `setup.py`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger You're right but I don't think its an issue for just running some random scripts locally which is the use case OP is interested in