# Unable to Install 'textpack' Library

Tags: python

I'm trying to install textpack (library for grouping similar strings)

I type

```
pip install textpack
```

But i get the error
    `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: command: /Users/raahimmuzaffar/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/ff/l8_9tcgj5ss8n3bg97y9mm780000gn/T/pip-install-9lq2x6rk/sklearn/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/ff/l8_9tcgj5ss8n3bg97y9mm780000gn/T/pip-install-9lq2x6rk/sklearn/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/ff/l8_9tcgj5ss8n3bg97y9mm780000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-iz_urgtz cwd: /private/var/folders/ff/l8_9tcgj5ss8n3bg97y9mm780000gn/T/pip-install-9lq2x6rk/sklearn/ Complete output (18 lines): The 'sklearn' PyPI package is deprecated, use 'scikit-learn' rather than 'sklearn' for pip commands.`

I have scikit-learn installed. How do i fix this?

Expected textpack to be installed

Comment: I hope this might help.
https://github.com/Anjok07/ultimatevocalremovergui/issues/522

Answer (score 1):

On the [`textpack` GitHub repo](https://github.com/lukewhyte/textpack/pulls) there is [this pull request](https://github.com/lukewhyte/textpack/pull/11) intended to fix your issue. I suggest you to trace that discussion.

In the meantime, you could clone the repo, implement the proposed change to `Pipfile` by yourself, and install the package locally (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471994/what-is-setup-py) for more info).

Answer (score 0):

Edit the version of **Dora** in **requirements.txt**, remove "==0.0.3" and only leave "Dora" alone.

Else:

Try clearing the pip cache by using `pip purge`

Else:

Try updating the **'scikit-learn'** or reinstall the **'scikit-learn'**.

To update **scikit-learn**:

```
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```